# Assembly - Parameter changes after register being pushed into the stack

Tags: function, assembly, parameters

I'm implementing selection sort using assembly code. In the selection sort function, right after I push the registers into the stack, the value of the parameters change 
Here's the call in the main, with SIZE =15

```
    array_selection_sort(arrayOfNumbers1, SIZE);
```

And here's the sort function

```
    void array_selection_sort(int arrayOfIntegers[], int arraySize)
{
__asm{
    // BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push esi
    push edi

    //assign variables
    //ebx = array, ecx = array size - 1, edi = j, edx as temp, esi and edi used for swapping
    mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
    mov ecx, arraySize
}
```

The arraySize change from 15 to 2130567168 right after the line

```
    move ebp, esp
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler assumes your parameters are in specific location on stack. When you push to stack, you change the value of the stack pointer and therefore mess with the compiler assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't name the compiler, calling conventions or whatever.

Many questions can be answered by checking the generated assembler, both the calling, and the generated function

- does the compiler generate any more code for this function? Maybe it already generates a stackframe.
- what kind of instruction does the compiler generate code for  mov ecx, arraySize ? register, EBP relative or ESP relative? If it is ESP relative, the compiler thinks it is is a frameless function, even if you generate the frame manually yourself.
- Check the calling code how parameters are prepared. You load the array by accessing [ebp+8], so assuming stack conventions, why not load the arraysize by using [ebp+12] ?